# When running "hedera-json-rpc-relay", how to configure a connection to Hedera Testnet?

Tags: javascript, json-rpc, hedera-hashgraph, hedera

I'm following the instructions on `hedera-json-rpc-relay`:
Specifically [`docs/configuration.md`](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-json-rpc-relay/blob/main/docs/configuration.md),
attempting to run the RPC relay connecting to Hedera Testnet:

```bash
HEDERA_NETWORK=TESTNET
OPERATOR_ID_MAIN=0.0.3996280
OPERATOR_KEY_MAIN=<redacted>
OPERATOR_ID_ETH_SENDRAWTRANSACTION=
OPERATOR_KEY_ETH_SENDRAWTRANSACTION=
CHAIN_ID=0x128
MIRROR_NODE_URL=https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/
E2E_RELAY_HOST=
```

Note that `OPERATOR_ID_MAIN` and `OPERATOR_KEY_MAIN` have been obtained for the portal,
and have successfully been used in other transactions.

The specific instruction for `HEDERA_NETWORK` is:

> Which network to connect to. Automatically populates the main node & mirror node endpoints. Can be MAINNET, PREVIEWNET, TESTNET or a map of network IPs -> node accountIds e.g. {"127.0.0.1:50211":"0.0.3"}

However, when I run `npm run start`, I get the following error `Error: unknown network: TESTNET`
... even though this explicitly is an allowed value according to the docs.

(Full output copied below the `<hr/>`).

What is the correct config to start the RPC relay and connect it to Hedera Testnet?

---

```
> start
> npx lerna exec --scope @hashgraph/json-rpc-server -- npm run start

lerna notice cli v6.4.1
lerna info versioning independent
lerna notice filter including "@hashgraph/json-rpc-server"
lerna info filter [ '@hashgraph/json-rpc-server' ]
lerna info Executing command in 1 package: "npm run start"

> @hashgraph/json-rpc-server@0.23.0-SNAPSHOT start
> node dist/index.js

[2023-04-21 03:25:43.036 +0000] INFO (rpc-server/97941 on admins-MBP): Configurations successfully loaded
/Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/client/NodeClient.cjs:279
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: unknown network: TESTNET
    at NodeClient._setNetworkFromName (/Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/client/NodeClient.cjs:279:15)
    at new NodeClient (/Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/client/NodeClient.cjs:94:14)
    at NodeClient.forName (/Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/node_modules/@hashgraph/sdk/lib/client/NodeClient.cjs:164:12)
    at RelayImpl.initClient (/Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/packages/relay/dist/lib/relay.js:69:35)
    at new RelayImpl (/Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/packages/relay/dist/lib/relay.js:42:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/packages/server/dist/server.js:57:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)

Node.js v18.15.0
npm ERR! Lifecycle script `start` failed with error: 
npm ERR! Error: command failed 
npm ERR!   in workspace: @hashgraph/json-rpc-server@0.23.0-SNAPSHOT 
npm ERR!   at location: /Users/user/code/hedera/hedera-json-rpc-relay/packages/server 
lerna ERR! npm run start exited 1 in '@hashgraph/json-rpc-server'
lerna ERR! npm run start exited 1 in '@hashgraph/json-rpc-server'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the config that was necessary:

```
HEDERA_NETWORK=testnet
OPERATOR_ID_MAIN=0.0.3996280
OPERATOR_KEY_MAIN=<...redacted...>
CHAIN_ID=0x128
MIRROR_NODE_URL=https://testnet.mirrornode.hedera.com/
```

Submitted [a patch](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-json-rpc-relay/pull/1113/files)
to add the sample files for the above,
plus equivalents for Hedera Mainnet and Hedera Previewnet as well.

Also, the error that occurred was because of this line:

```
HEDERA_NETWORK=TESTNET
```

It essentially failed because it only accepted all lowercase.
This [has also been fixed](https://github.com/hashgraph/hedera-json-rpc-relay/pull/1113/files#diff-1a45371580beb8c8be0c7e9788cd7417302bba50a5732c6b31dbb0e69e4769b9R51)
in the same patch,
so now the original config from the question will start working as well.